# mount .img file to extract data

Tags: data-recovery

I have an HDD (2.0 TB WD20EARS) with NTFS that crashed. The disk was pure storage and never had been used for OS installation. I cannot mount it to my mint pc but I can get .img file from gnome-disks. Getting the .img file I got almost 2 GB were non readable and replaced with zero's. After I got the .img file I tried to mount it on but I cannot mount it. Is there a way to extract the data from inside the .img file or they are lost?

Comment: in all honesty, the Linux NTFS implementation is significantly less mature than the Windows one – I think your safest bet is using Windows to try and repair the NTFS file system. You could (and probably should) make an image beforehand, in case anything goes wrong (e.g. the disk completely fails hardware-wise, which by the way is the best explanation for 2GB of zeros).

Comment: Have you tried running `fsck` / `fsck.ntfs` on the image file?

Comment: @FelixJN Haven't thought of that. I will try it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but it depends on whether you copied the entire disk (like `/dev/sda`) or you only copied a partition (like `/dev/sda1`).

**Case 1:**

If you copied the entire partition you need to attach your disk as a loop device. You can do this using `losetup`, and then mount the loop device with the `mount` command. A little example of this is below.

Attach your disk as a loop device:

```
losetup --find --show disk.img
```

That will show the a output like `/dev/loopX` when `X` is a number, for example `/dev/loop1`

See the partitions into your disk with `lsblk`:

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop1            7:2    0 447,1G  0 loop  
├──loop1p1      259:2   0 223,6G  0 part 
└──loop1p2      259:2   0 223,6G  0 part 
sda              8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sda1           8:1    0 931,5G  0 part  /
```

Mount the loop partitions with `mount` command:

```
#create folder for each partition:
 mkdir /mnt/part1
 mkdir /mnt/part2

#mount each partitions:
 mount /dev/loop1p1 /mnt/part1
 mount /dev/loop1p2 /mnt/part2
```

**Case 2:**

If you copied only the partition, you would use the mount command. An example of this is below.

Create the directory when the disk will be mounted:

```
mkdir /mnt/mydisk
```

An then mount your disk:

```
mount disk.img /mnt/mydisk
```

Comment: WD20EARS is a disk that supports 4KiB sector size, so in Case 1, you might need `losetup --find --show --sector-size 4096 --partscan disk.img` if the OS that originally formatted the disk did support 4K sectors and used GPT partitioning.